# Page Life Expectancy (PLE), where to start?

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have inherited a SQL server {*2012 (SP3), but this question is intended to be generic*} we are using SCOM to monitor it.  Previously I was getting an alert once or twice a month for PLE < 300.  Now I am getting sometimes 2 or 3 a day.

There are multiple blog posts about PLE, a few tools you can get to monitor it, and many differing opinions about what is good, bad or indifferent. In the end there are a lot of variables.  No solutions are one size fits all.  Low PLE is not a problem so much as it is a symptom, with lots of potential causes, and related measures to consider.

{**this paragraph might not add value to the question, I am open to removing it**} I think everyone can agree that PLE falling to 299 once a month during an overnight report creation, is a symptom that does not need to be addressed (*assuming the report completes before business hours*).  Most can also agree that PLE consistently at 350, is not good.  There are a handful of cause to look at before making hardware change, with queries and index being near the top.

After reading about a dozen blog posts about PLE. I have tried to narrow down the key symptoms to get a good picture of what is going on.  The query below is what I came up with. It gives values for 4 Buffer Manager items that interconnect with PLE

- 'Page life expectancy'
- 'Free list stalls/sec'
- 'Lazy writes/sec'
- 'Buffer cache hit ratio'

...

```
SELECT [object_name],
[counter_name],
[cntr_value] FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-performance-counters-transact-sql
WHERE [counter_name] = 'Page life expectancy' --if multiple NUMA on a server should return multiple Nodes, 
OR [counter_name] = 'Free list stalls/sec'  -- Number of requests per second that had to wait for a free page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance-monitor/sql-server-buffer-manager-object
OR [counter_name] = 'Lazy writes/sec' --Flushes of dirty pages before a checkpoint runs.  
OR [counter_name] = 'Buffer cache hit ratio' --percentage of pages found in the buffer cache without having to read from disk you want this ratio to be high
Order by [counter_name] DESC, [object_name];
```

Additionally if you are looking at Lazy Writes on an inherited server you should check Recovery Interval

```
EXEC sp_configure @configname='recovery interval (min)';  --The  'config_value' default 0 indicates SQL is applying Checkpoints completely automatically https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-recovery-interval-server-configuration-option
```

If this first query does not return values:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters;  --If no values from the firs query, an value of 0 here indicates a seperate issue  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-performance-counters-transact-sql
```

I have a pretty good idea what all these values represent, and how they work together.  I have included comments and sources in my code above.

**My question is two part**

1. Is my list of buffer items/values above adequate for a starting place when examining PLE? (*i.e. values that will always be helpful to consider together, should something excluded or included*)
2. How to put the values in good context with each other?  (*i.e. there is a good [answer here saying "Check the Free List Stalls/sec value as well. If above 2, consider adding memory to the server"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55318/lazy-writes-performance-issues/55319#55319) while the body of the answer is helpful, I don't think a value of 2 for 'Free List Stalls/sec' is a problem on most instances*)

NOTE: This question is not about solving the PLE issue, it is about how/where to start looking when assessing the symptoms. Your Doctor checks your Pules, Blood Pressure, Respirations, and Temperature at the start of every exam.

**Edit 4/13/2018; Attempt to Clarify**
This is not about knee jerk reactions like checking indexes or waits. This is about identifying other native SQL performance data that should always be examined with PLE.  PLE is one of the Buffer Management Objects, what other Buffer Management Objects or Performance Counters should or should not always be part of queries when you really do want to look at buffer management?

Comment: PLE of 350, why does everyone have to agree that this is not good? For some workloads this is perfectly fine and in fact expected. Having a magic threshold like 300 and alerts keyed off of that is the part that's not good IMHO.

Comment: @AaronBertrand :) "**Most**  can also". But yeah no absolutes here.

Comment: Well, you could also say most people think a 4 minute mile is good. If I ever have a 10 minute mile I'll be ecstatic. 350 might be perfectly normal for a given workload, and it might actually be great for a LOT of workloads. If you really want to know about PLE (and Brent explains exactly why you shouldn't focus on that number, especially in isolation), you need to teach SCOM to alert on drastic changes based on your specific workload, not some magic number it pulled from a blog post in 2002. Your PLE is lower now than it was all week, but what *actual problem* do you have? Do you have one?

Comment: @AaronBertrand RE:"but what actual problem do you have? Do you have one?" that is exactly what I want to be able to find out.  When you run a 10 minute mile and your pulse is high, you are not worried.  But when you are sitting on the couch and your pulse is high, you also want to check a couple of other things like your BP and Respirations. If/when you check the PLE vital signs what else do you check?

Comment: I guess what I'm suggesting is that you don't need to panic every time PLE drops. There isn't always going to be a problem to solve. I wouldn't have anything set up to alert on PLE *alone* because it is so rarely an indication of some problem I can solve, or a problem at all.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I concur, I am with you 100% on that last comment.  I am looking at all 4 of the vitals in combination, and I am still pretty sure I don't have an issue (on the instance that started me on this quest).  It's a VM I could just throw some Memory at it and I would probably stop getting the PLE alerts. But I don't want to just do that. I have checked waits, I have checked indexes, I balance the existing memory better (with OS), I really think it is fine. I know I don't want to look at PLE alone, but I am not sure what else (related) to look at with it.

Comment: Well, you can just ignore PLE. You are not observing a problem, your users are not complaining about a problem, so don't let some PLE number make you chase unicorns. Make SCOM alert you on actual symptoms, like high waits in a specific category or severe drops in actual buffer pool usage, not an imaginary 300 threshold of PLE on its own. What you need to monitor for *specifically* will depend a lot more on your workload, your system, your usage patterns, etc. than on some blind list your peers might provide to you.

Answer (score 15):

**You basically asked, "What should I do when Page Life Expectancy changes?"**

**My answer: nothing.** I don't start by looking at Page Life Expectancy. That metric made sense in the SQL Server 7/2000 days when it was all that we had, but today, in 2018, we can do better.

Start by looking at wait stats - that tells you what SQL Server is waiting on.

I don't care whether PLE is 300 or 3,000 - tell me what you're WAITING on, SQL Server, and then I'll go troubleshoot that metric.

My personal favorite way to check waits is to use the open source [sp_BlitzFirst](https://www.brentozar.com/askbrent/) (disclaimer: I wrote it.) By default, it takes a 5-second sample of your server's metrics and gives you a few guesses as to why it's slow right now.

Because you like writing long questions, you'll probably also like these:

```
sp_BlitzFirst @SinceStartup = 1;
```

The first result set gives you your waits since startup, and:

```
sp_Blitz @ExpertMode = 1, @Seconds = 60;
```

Takes a longer sample, and tells your waits over that time range.

Wait stats can be kind of cryptic, so next to every wait type, I link to the [SQLskills wait stats repository](https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits) for that wait type. You can just copy/paste out the name of your top wait type, go to their site, and learn more about what causes that wait and how to fix it.

If PLE is dropping due to queries reading a lot of data pages from disk, for example, you might see PAGEIOLATCH% wait types. If it's dropping due to queries getting huge memory grants, you might see RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE. If PLE isn't the problem, then you'll see different wait types altogether.

Comment: First I want to say; I have read many of your blog posts and watched your videos, and have learned a lot thank you.  But this is not an answer to the question.   If the PLE = 300, and the Lazy Writes = 500,000 and the Free list stalls/sec = 0 then I don't have a problem. I can run my little query using only OOTB parts, and go on to other issues.  Those issues may be excessive waits, slow quires or something on a different instance completely unrelated.

Comment: You asked, "How should I examine PLE?" I answered, "You shouldn't."

Comment: First off, I know v. little about SQL Server. However, I think the critical part of @BrentOzar 's answer is `Start by looking at wait stats - that tells you what SQL Server is waiting on.`. i.e. where is performance being impacted? Oraclke has the Oracle Wait Interface - same deal. Tweaking numbers on a dial is not the same as getting to the root of a problem. p.s. +1 to you and Brent - you for a well-written question and Brent for a well-written answer!

Comment: Rereading my question this morning, I can see where your read it as "What should I do when Page Life Expectancy changes?", but that is not what I want to know., I have read many blogs (including yours) about PLE, I am going to try to clarify the question more.

Comment: @JamesJenkins I'm gonna be honest: you probably just want to start a new question from scratch. As it stands, your question is really clear that PLE isn't your problem - you yourself even say, "Low PLE is not a problem so much as it is a symptom." You also say "Your Doctor checks" and then lists metrics, and you've got a bunch of industry experts (doctors) here who are telling you that we don't look at PLE. It's like going to a doctor and saying, "Tell me what you look at when you examine toenail growth rate." We simply don't look at that.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while since I asked this question, I have learned a lot since then.

As Brent points out in [his answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/203788/21924) PLE alerts by themselves don't really tell you anything.  By design, these pages should come and go, if they don't stay long when no longer needed, that is fine.

Nevertheless, I have one specific instance throwing PLE alerts several times per day, I have been looking at it with several tools including query store, and not finding anything that needs attention. Even if I added memory, it does not look like the PLE alerts would stop.  I went looking for a way to "Prove" if more memory was needed or not.

On small SQL instances with 4GB of available RAM, 75% or 3GB can be devoted to the plan cache. Normally this is **NOT** purged out with data pages, that PLE alerts on.  I found a couple of ways of looking what was happening with memory and the plan cache.

- https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/plan-cache-and-optimizing-for-adhoc-workloads/
- https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/07/tsql2sday-how-much-plan-cache-history-do-you-have/

Ultimately I developed (*leveraging on links above*) the query below that shows the life expectancy (in minutes) for cache plans.

```
    --plan cache Life expectancy
    SELECT sys.dm_exec_cached_plans.objtype AS [CacheType] 
    ,    COUNT_BIG(*) AS [Total Plans]
    ,    SUM(CAST(sys.dm_exec_cached_plans.size_in_bytes AS DECIMAL(18, 2))) / 1024 / 1024 AS [Total MBs]
    ,   AVG(sys.dm_exec_cached_plans.usecounts) AS [Avg Use Count]
    ,   AVG (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, PH_Time.creation_time, (GETDATE()))) AS [Avg Age in Minutes]
    FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans
    left join (
                Select  plan_handle
                , Min (creation_time) as creation_time --A plan can have several unique related quiries, this gets just one time per plan
                from sys.dm_exec_query_stats
                group by plan_handle
                ) as PH_Time On sys.dm_exec_cached_plans.plan_handle = PH_Time.plan_handle
    --left join sys.dm_exec_query_stats On sys.dm_exec_cached_plans.plan_handle = sys.dm_exec_query_stats.plan_handle 
    GROUP BY objtype
    ORDER BY [Total MBs] DESC
    GO
```

While no single item by itself is conclusive, a strong argument can be made that if the average life on plans in cache is longer than, the time between queries being re-run, no additional memory is needed. The specific time will very by use case.

There are a lot of reasons that plans are recompiled, see related [Why is Query Store missing details?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/234483/21924) Early on, I focused a lot on high recompile with PLE, and did not find a helpful correlation.

**TL:DR** Memory is intended to have things come and go, low PLE is not a problem.  **BUT** by design, plans used often should stay in the memory long enough to be reused. If you can show that plans are staying in memory long enough to be reused, it is difficult to justify adding memory without some other indicator.